# Python - regex search for string which starts and ends with the given text

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of files, and I want to keep only the ones which start with 'test_' and end with '.py'.  I want the regex to only return the text inside the 'test_' and '.py'.  I do not want .pyc files included.

I have tried:

```
>>>filename = 'test_foo.py'
>>>re.search(r'(?<=test_).+(?=\.py)', filename).group()
foo.py
```

but it still returns the extension, and will allow '.pyc' extensions (which I do not want).  I'm pretty sure it's the '+' which is consuming the whole string.

This works as a fallback, but I would prefer a regex solution:

```
>>>filename = 'test_foo.py'
>>>result = filename.startswith('test_') and filename.endswith('.py')
>>>result = result.replace('test_', '').replace('.py', '')
>>>print result
foo
```

Comment: Why would you prefer a regex solution? I think your fallback is actually a better approach.

Comment: You can test it out: http://regex101.com/r/qU7iS2. It seems to work ok, maybe it's the `group()` method that is getting it wrong?

Comment: @Keyser: respectfully disagree: http://regex101.com/r/lR3lK7

Comment: What is the value of `filename`? When I set `filename` to `"foobarbaz.pyc"` and run your exact code, I don't get a match.

Comment: When I set `filename` to `"test_foobarbaz.pyc"` and run your first code, I get back `"foobarbaz"`. The code seems to do what you want. Please give a real example (including the value of `filename`), and the expected result.

Comment: @interjay, I do not want to include the .pyc files; just the .py files.

Comment: @Keyser: Ah. Got it now. You're right.

Comment: OK. The sentence "it still returns the '.py' or '.pyc'." seemed to indicate that your only problem is with what part of the string is returned. (And note that it does *not* return the .pyc as part of the result as you claim).

Comment: @interjay Read the first line of the question :)

Comment: @interjay; As Keyser said, the first line of the question states what I want, but yes, the line you are referring to is confusing.

Comment: @Keyser I did. I also read the rest of the question, which is misleading (e.g. the first example shows the .pyc being returned when it actually isn't, and seems to indicate that is the issue).

Comment: Your edit is still wrong. Your code does *not* return the extension as you claim. It certainly doesn't return "foobarbaz.py" when the filename didn't even contain that string. Please copy/paste actual code and output that you ran instead of guessing what Python would do.

Comment: @interjay; you got me; I was recalling code that I knew didn't work, converting it in my head to be context-free, and not testing the code I wrote in the question.  But now I cannot for the life of me replicate the old problem!  There must have been a problem somewhere else; this is embarrassing.  I've flagged this question for removal.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your pattern matches any string that comes after by `test_` and before `.py`, but that doesn't restrict it from having other characters before the `test_` or after the `.py`.

You need to use start (`^`) and end (`$`) [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html). Also, don't forget to escape the `.` character. Try this pattern:

```
(?<=^test_).+(?=\.py$)
```

Comment: That did it!  I had tried putting a '$' after the lookahead but that didn't work.  This did, though.  Thanks!  PS: Yes, I forgot to escape the '.' in my question.

Comment: The positive look behind isn't needed with the `^`, right? Seems like all you need is what iCodez suggested.

Comment: @Keyser I believe it is. Without that, the pattern would match `some_test_foo.py`. Of course, you *can* do it without any lookarounds at all.

Comment: Y how about a capturing group around the (.+)

Comment: Personally I would skip all this look behind business and just use a capture group to get the part you want: `re.search(r'test_(.+)\.py$', filename).group(1)`

Comment: @Keyser Yes, exactly, you can do that without any problem. It's simpler and probably what I would've gone with, but it does slightly modify the behavior expression--you'd need to extract the group, rather than the entire matched text if you just want to see just the text between `test_` and `.py`. That's a perfectly valid solution as well.

Comment: Hey! Can somebody help me in extracting the ouput 'Ultra HD (4K)' from the string - Operating System: AndroidUltra HD (4K) 3840 x 2160 Pixels30

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
import re

files = [
"test_1.py",
"Test.py",
"test.pyc",
"test.py",
"script.py"]

print [x for x in files if re.search("^test_.*py$", x)]
```

output:

```
['test_1.py']
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for; I need to keep the lookahead and lookbehind since I don't want the 'test_' and '.py'.  I made an edit to my question specifying this.

Comment: @zalpha314 - Oh, well, I posted before that.

Comment: Yes; my apologies for that.